# Assigning multiple pictures in controls Picturebox

Tags: c#

100 picturebox have on my screen that represents 100 pictures corresponding to 100 dishes.
What I need is to refresh the images of 100 by 100 but I get the following error on the line foreach (PictureBox miPicture in this.Controls):

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred
>   in Cheff2000.exe
>
> Additional information: Unable to cast object of type
>   'System.Windows.Forms.Button' type 'System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox'.

My void is:

```
    private void CapturaRecetasBtnFam()     // SOLO Captura las primeras Recetas de la Fam cuando se hace Click en el BtnFam-n
    {
        BlanquearRec();
        oListaFamRec = objFamRec.Listar();
        var miFami = oListaFamRec.Find(DescFam => DescFam.Descripcion == NomFam);
        // The cod captured the ongoing fam
        string CodFam = oListaFamRec[miFami.Posicion - 1].Codigo;
        oListaReceta = objRec.ListarPosicionEnFam();
        var Result = from sigreceta in oListaReceta where sigreceta.Familia == CodFam select sigreceta;

        // We assign text and images to objects (Button and PictureBox) of Recipes
        ContRec1 = 1;
        ContRec2 = 1;
        foreach (Vi_Receta Rec in Result)
        {
            // Textos a los Button
            nomBoton = "BtnRec" + Convert.ToString(ContRec1);
            nomPicture = "PicRec" + Convert.ToString(ContRec2);
            foreach (Control miObjeto in this.Controls)
            {
                if (miObjeto is Button && miObjeto.Name == nomBoton)
                {
                    miObjeto.Text = Rec.Descripcion;

                    ContRec1++;
                }
            }
            // PictureBox pictures
            foreach (PictureBox miPicture in this.Controls)
            {
                if (miPicture.Name == nomPicture && miPicture.Name == nomPicture)
                {
                    miPicture.Image = Rec.Foto == null ? null : ConvertByteArrayToImage(Rec.Foto);
                }
            }


        }
    }
```

Comment: It would appear that one of the `Controls` in `this` is a button, you need to check for pictureboxes... What have you researched?

Comment: The problem is here: `foreach (PictureBox miPicture in this.Controls)` this enumerates through all the controls, including buttons, which causes the error.

Comment: Thank you all for your valuable feedback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in your `foreach` loop. The way you have it now, it enumerates through all the controls, including buttons, which causes the error. It should look something like this (untested):

```
foreach (Control cPicture in this.Controls)
{
    if (cPicture is PictureBox)
    {
        PictureBox miPicture = (PictureBox)cPicture;

        if (miPicture.Name == nomPicture && miPicture.Name == nomPicture)
        {
            miPicture.Image = Rec.Foto == null ? null : ConvertByteArrayToImage(Rec.Foto);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah Mints97, I know but still do not have the necessary score. Thanks again.

Comment: @MarioEscudero: that is strange, I always believed that rep did not matter in accepting answers...

Comment: @MarioEscudero: voting up and accepting answers are different things. To accept, you have to click the gray checkmark below the voting buttons. please visit the [tour page](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and other *help* sections such as the FAQ to get yourself familiar with how stackoverflow works =)

Comment: @MarioEscudero: yes, correct! And - welcome to StackOverflow!